# XNA & Farseer - Collision with a random edged shape

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, physics, farseer

I have setup Farseer in my XNA project and have a player body which falls endlessly because of gravity. What I want the player to do is "land" on the random edged image I have in the window using the create shape from image function. How do I make the player body object collide with the shape?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XNA Farseer - How to actually make it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398767/xna-farseer-how-to-actually-make-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything explicitly ... just add the body into the same world and they will collide based on the properties you've given them (mass, shape, etc.).

```
   1:  //Create a World object with zero gravity
   2:  World world = new World(Vector2.Zero);
   3:              
   4:  //We create a body object and make it dynamic (movable)
   5:  Body myBody = world.CreateBody();
   6:  myBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
   7:   
   8:  //We create a circle shape with a radius of 0.5 meters
   9:  CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(0.5f);
  10:   
  11:  //We fix the body and shape together using a Fixture object
  12:  Fixture fixture = myBody.CreateFixture(circleShape);
```

This code sample is from the [documentation](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home). I highly suggest downloading the demos and seeing how each demo is constructed in code. it will greatly help you :-)